# Checking the resolution of html page

Tags: html

Hi
How can we check the resolution of the html page?
 If the page is online.
 Thanks

Comment: How do you mean by "resolution"? Width and height? Screen resolution of the client? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with Javascript and i think [Screen Resolution Detection](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jscreen.htm) will help you

Answer (score 2):

html pages dont have "resolutions".

They may or may not have a fixed width and height controlled by the page style, which is controlled partly by the CSS that the page uses. Or it could be set by javascript. The width and height may be in pixels or in character size units, which will change depending on what character size the user has set in their browser.

What is it you are trying to achieve?